# GPT call returns empty string from API

Tags: openai-api, react-tsx

I am attempting to use the GPT API to ask it a question and get a yes or no response but I keep on getting an empty string back from it, not sure which part I'm doing wrong. This is for a React project.

Currently I have the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Stack } from '@mui/material';
import Home from './pages/Home';

const API_KEY = "" // this has an actual API key in it...

const App = () => {
  const [textScript, settextScript] = useState("");
  const [isTextScriptAPI, setIsTextScriptAPI] = useState("");

  async function callOpenAIAPI() {
    console.log("Calling API");

    const prompt = `Is this text about soccer? yes or no ${text}`;

    const APIBody = {
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt,
      temperature: 0,
      max_tokens: 100,
      top_p: 1,
      frequency_penalty: 0.0,
      presence_penalty: 0.0,
      stop: ["\n"]
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(APIBody)
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);

      if (data.choices && data.choices.length > 0) {
        const generatedText = data.choices[0].text.trim();
        setIsTextScriptAPI(generatedText);
      } else {
        setIsTextScriptAPI("No response from the API");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      setIsTextScriptAPI("API call failed");
    }
  }

  return (
    <Stack className="bgImage">
      <Home />
      <textarea
        onChange={(e) => setTextScript(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Enter text'
        cols={75}
        rows={10}
      />
      <Button onClick={callOpenAIAPI}>
        SCAN
      </Button>
      {isTextScript !== "" && (
        <h3>This text {textScript} soccer text</h3>
      )}
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default App;
```

and the API call returns this

```
model: 'text-davinci-003', choices: Array(1), …}
choices
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
{text: '', index: 0, logprobs: null, finish_reason: 'stop'}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
```

Which does not appear to contain any response from the API

Answer (score 0):

Change `stop: ["\n"]` because it generates `\n` first thing in the response hence: `finish_reason: 'stop'`.